# Connect to Azure DevOps TFS from a Mac

Tags: tfs

Currently using old version of Eclipse, with the TFS plugin.

The plugin is no longer supported in newer versions of Eclipse, and is not actively maintained.

Moving to GIT is not an option.

Are there other tools to connect to TFS on a Mac?